# What's the best practice for creating computed (dynamic/virtual) attributes on entries?

Tags: entrymodel, attribute

What is the best practice for defining an attribute on an Entry that isn't persistent? For example, I want to create a formatted string from two separate values stored in fields on the entry, but don't need to store the computed value in a field or in the database.

I realize I can do this in a template variable like so:

`{% set fullName = entry.firstName ~ " " ~ entry.lastName %}`

... but, it would be much better if I could define this in a more global way so it can be used any time I'm dealing with an Entry within a specific Section like so:

`{{ entry.fullName }}`

I've read about custom Modules but that seems like overkill. Also, Craft may not offer any API to do something like this, but Yii might?

Halp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [behaviors](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/extending-system-components.html#behaviors) to add new methods to system components. See the link above for documentation. A behavior is a class that extends [yii\base\Behavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-behavior) and is attached to a component using the `EVENT_DEFINE_BEHAVIORS` event.

First you define the class that provides your custom method:

```php
use yii\base\Behavior;

class FullNameBehavior extends Behavior {
    public function fullName() {
        return "{$this->owner->firstName} {$this->owner->lastName}";
    }
}
```

The attach that behavior to the `Entry` class:

```php
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\DefineBehaviorsEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

// init() method in a module
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_DEFINE_BEHAVIORS,
    function (DefineBehaviorsEvent $e) {
        $e->sender->attachBehaviors([
            FullNameBehavior::class,
        ]);
    }
);
```

Now you can use the method in Twig:

```twig
{{ entry.fullName }}
```

You can put the behavior class and the event hook in a [module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html#preparation).

#### Alternative approaches

I don't really like behaviors in general, as it's very hard to find out where their methods are defined if you don't know about them. Also, tacking endless additional methods onto a class that doesn't really have anything to do with them is kind of bad design.

Instead, consider the following solutions:

- Use a [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html) or a [Twig filter or function](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/extending-twig.html#register-a-twig-extension) to display the full name consistently.
- Install the [Preparse Field](https://plugins.craftcms.com/preparse-field) plugin and store the full name in a preparse field.
- If feasible, you could represent people as [Users](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/users.html) instead of Entries – they come with a computed [fullName property](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-user.html#fullname) by default.